# How to search a file and move to multiple destination directories?

Tags: find, mv

How to search single file and move to multiple folders using find command?

I tried below command, but no luck.

```
find /export/logs/tmp/logs/* -type f -name f_apec_`echo $(date  +"%Y-%m-%d")`_1 -exec mv -v {} /export/logs/nucleus1/ /export/logs/nucleus2/ \;
```

Comment: Does it copy to the first directory and not the second?

Comment: How can you possibly _move_ (as opposed to _copy_) a file to two different places? At lease one of them will have to be a copy or  a link. For hardlinks, the directories have to be on the same file system.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot move a file to multiple directories, but you can copy it to all destinations and to the last move it using your own command.

```
find /export/logs/tmp/logs/ -type f -name "f_apec_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")_1" -exec echo cp -v '{}' /export/logs/nucleus1/ \; -exec echo mv -v '{}' /export/logs/nucleus2/ \;
```

Here also you can copy a file to multiple directories using `xargs`:

```
echo dir1/ dir2/ dir3/ | xargs -n1 cp /path/to/Onefile
```

Comment: `&&` is a shell operator, you can't use it like that. You could have two `-exec` predicates though which would be *AND*ed together.

Answer (score 0):

First you are using `mv` which moves a file, not copy it.
You need to use `cp`, but `cp` can copy multiple files to a single destination.

You'll need to execute `cp` multiple times. One solution you can use is creating a simple script that copies the argument to multiple destinations. Then in your `find .. -exec {}` command run the script with the file as an argument, and copy it multiple times inside your script.